# keras model fit_generator ValueError: Error when checking model target: expected cropping2d_4 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (32, 1)

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I'm trying to use keras model.fit_generator() to fit a model, below is my definition of the generator:

```
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
IMG_PATH_PREFIX = "./data/IMG/"
def generator(samples, batch_size=64):
    num_samples = len(samples)
    while 1: # Loop forever so the generator never terminates
        shuffle(samples)
        for offset in range(0, num_samples, batch_size):
            batch_samples = samples[offset:offset+batch_size]

            images = []
            angles = []
            for batch_sample in batch_samples:
                name = IMG_PATH_PREFIX  + batch_sample[0].split('/')[-1]

                center_image = cv2.imread(name)
                center_angle = float(batch_sample[3])                

                images.append(center_image)
                angles.append(center_angle)

        X_train = np.array(images)
        y_train = np.array(angles)

        #X_train = np.expand_dims(X_train, axis=0)
        #y_train = np.expand_dims(y_train, axis=1)
        print("X_train shape: ", X_train.shape, " y_train shape:", y_train.shape)
        #print("X train: ", X_train)
        yield X_train, y_train 

train_generator = generator(train_samples, batch_size = 32)
validation_generator = generator(validation_samples, batch_size = 32)
```

Here the output shape is:
X_train shape:  (32, 160, 320, 3)  y_train shape: (32,)

The model fit code is:

```
model = Sequential()
#cropping layer
model.add(Cropping2D(cropping=((50,20), (1,1)), input_shape=(160,320,3),  dim_ordering='tf'))
model.compile(loss = "mse", optimizer="adam")
model.fit_generator(train_generator, samples_per_epoch= len(train_samples), validation_data=validation_generator, nb_val_samples=len(validation_samples), nb_epoch=3)
```

Then I get the error message:

ValueError: Error when checking model target: expected cropping2d_6 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (32, 1)

Could someone help let me know what's the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big question here is : do you know what you are trying to do ?

1) If you read [here](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#cropping2d), the input is a 4D tensor and the output is ALSO a 4D tensor. Your target is a 2D tensor of shape (batch_size,1). So of course, when keras tries to compute the error between the output which has 3D (without batch dimension) and the target which has 1D (without batch dimension), it can not make sense out of that. Outputs and targets must have the same dimensions.

2) Do you know what cropping2D is actually doing ? It is cropping your images... So removing values at the beginning and end of your cropping dimensions. In your case you are outputing images of shape (90, 218, 3). This is not a prediction, there is no weight to train on this layer so no reason to fit the "model". Your model is just cropping images. No training needed for that.